# Should questions asking about the existence of an undocumented feature on a website be systemically closed or left open?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

One moderator closed [How can I upload a file to a specific folder when adding files to an existing archive in the Wayback Machine via the web interface?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170373/18147) with the reason:

> If the feature is not included in the end-user docs (product brochure, help articles, etc.), it not exists. It is your responsibility to thoroughly review them. On the other hand, **questions asking for hidden features are off-topic**. Also, veiled reverse engineering requests, veiled requests to develop workarounds, and veiled requests for tailor-made solutions are not allowed as questions should be clear. Such kinds of questions (reverse engineering, workarounds, solution development might require lengthy discussion in meta before being allowed. –
> [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n)**♦** [yesterday](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/170373/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-when-adding-files-to-an-existing-ar?noredirect=1#comment158202_170373)

I had never read that questions asking for hidden features were off-topic. I assume that hidden features refer to features that are not mentioned in the official documentation.

Should questions asking about the existence of a undocumented feature on a website be systemically closed or left open?

undocumented = not mentioned in the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

No, asking about the existence of an undocumented feature on a website should *not* cause the question to be closed. Reason: Some websites don't document all the features they have. Examples:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169122/18147: "The single() function is one of the many undocumented functions in Google Sheets"
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166568/18147 "I still don't understand why it's undocumented but here's how to do it for all pages"
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149480/18147 "FLATTEN is still an undocumented Google Sheets function"

Comment: Please elaborate for each example on what is the undocumented feature.

Comment: @Rubén I added it

Comment: Please add an [argument map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_map).

Comment: @Rubén why do you want an argument map? What would it add to the answer?